# Mapping an array of classes to remove whitespace from values swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, struct, filter

I have a struct and an array of my structs as follows

```
struct Products{
    var ProductType: String
    var ProductName: String
    var ProductLink: String
}

var CleaningProductsArray = [Products]()
```

When I write to my array of structs the ProductName Variable inside it sometimes can be written by the user with trailing whitespaces. I would like to return a version of the CleaningProductsArray but with all instances of ProductName having any trailing whitespaces removed. I have been trying to achieve with map as below but does not return what I would like it to. What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
let trimmed = CleaningProductsArray.map{ $0.ProductName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) }
```

Comment: Trimming whitespace is a view concern, your business logic shouldn't know anything about it. By the time you've made a `Products` model, you should have already cleaned up/parsed/formatted the user input, so that the rest of your code doesn't have to worry about it

Comment: Unrelated but important: `Products` should be singular (it only models one product), and Swift's convention is to use `lowerCamelCase` for local variables, properties, etc. Also, there's no need to prefix every field of a `Product` with `Product`. We know the `name` is a `ProductName` because it belongs to... a `Product`.

Comment: +1 for Alexander's comment about naming conventions. These conventions are very strong in Swift, and you should learn to follow them.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is:

```swift
let trimmed: [Products] = CleaningProductsArray.map { product in
    var adjusted = product
    adjusted.ProductName = product.ProductName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    return adjusted
}
```

As it was correctly mentioned in the comments, there are things you can improve in your overall code design.

You could start with converting your model to meet Swift naming standards, which means not using plural for `Products` since the objects of this type describe a single product, and removing the `product` prefix from properties since its obvious from the context that they describe a "Product". Ideally you would also make the properties immutable, to make passing them around safer (google "Benefits of immutability"). You should create some other object responsible for collecting all the data for your product objects.

```swift
struct Product {
    let type: String
    let name: String
    let link: String
}
```

Also, you should never use uppercased names for your variables/constants/properties/functions in Swift, so it's best to replace the `CleaningProductsArray` with `cleaningProductsArray` for the sake of readability. Uppercased names are reserved for types. Also you might want to drop the `Array` suffix since it's obvious from the type that it is an array

```swift
var cleaningProducts = [Product]()
let trimmed: [Product] = cleaningProducts.map {
    Product(
        type: $0.type,
        name: $0.name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces),
        link: $0.link
    )
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to have the trimming done in `Product.init` as then it will always trim it wherever it is created, but still allow the above map, and simply the call site, as  `Product(type: $0.type, name: $0.name, link: $0.link)` although this change should make this map unneseccary.

Comment: I believe something else should handle the trimming, for example the method that gets the data from the text field and assigns it to the Product object. Init should not be handling this kind of logic.